# Linear independence of three vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

I have following exercise:

> Find all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ when vectors
>   $ \left[
>     \begin{array}{c}
>       1\\
>       1\\
>       1
>     \end{array}
> \right] $,
>   $ \left[
>     \begin{array}{c}
>       1\\
>       2+z^3\\
>       1
>     \end{array}
> \right] $ and
>   $ \left[
>     \begin{array}{c}
>       1\\
>       1\\
>       2+z^6
>     \end{array}
> \right] $ are linear independent.

The definition says if
$$\alpha \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      1\\
      1\\
      1
    \end{array}
\right] + \beta \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      1\\
      2+z^3\\
      1
    \end{array}
\right] + \gamma \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      1\\
      1\\
      2+z^6
    \end{array}
\right] = 0 \iff \alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0$$
then the vectors are linear independent.

Then I can write following equations:
$$\begin{cases}
\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 0 \\[2ex] 
\alpha + (2+z^3)\beta + \gamma = 0 \\[2ex] 
\alpha + \beta + (2+z^6)\gamma = 0
\end{cases}
$$

However I do not know how should I solve it? Do I only have to ensure that $2+z^3\not=0$ and $2+z^6\not=0$?

Comment: if $2+z^3 = 1$, then the first two vectors are the same, so the vectors are not linearly independent

Comment: You can write your system of equation in matrix form, say $Ax=0$ where $x$ is the vector $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$. It is known that $Ax=0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$ if $A$ is invertible, which is equivalent to ask for $\det A \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

Subtract the first equation from the second you get $(2+z^3-1)\beta=0$.

To ensure $(2+z^3-1)\beta=0\implies \beta=0$ we must have $2+z^3-1\neq 0$.

Similarly we must have $2+z^6-1\neq 0$ by subtracting the first equation from the third equation.